# how to detect when savehtml fails?

Tags: php

This is a sample php code that creates the dom and saves the html.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$root = $doc->createElement('html');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$head = $doc->createElement('head');
$head = $root->appendChild($head);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $head->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

How, can we catch when the save or saveHTML() fails?

I appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

I want the catch the error in the following code. I have purposely constructed a random string. I want to load this string to a dom document and catch the error.

```
<?php


$str = "uyiuyiuhkjh<><><.,><.<.";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$saved = $dom->saveHTML();


//This doesnt work. 
if ($saved === false){

    echo 'Unable to save DOM document';

}
else{

    echo $saved;
}



?>
```

UPDATE 2:

The following code will fail. i.e it doesn't recognize the nav tag when parsing. It gives an error Tag nav invalid in Entity.

```
<?php


$str = "<html> <head> </head> <body> <nav> </nav> </body> </html>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$saved = $dom->saveHTML();

if ($saved === false){

    echo 'Unable to save DOM document';

}
else{

    echo $saved;
}



?>
```

Now, to suppress the error i can use libxml_use_internal_errors(true); but now the error message disappears but the $dom->saveHTML() still doesn't return false or empty so it is hard to know when saveHTML or loadHTML had an error. Please help!!

Comment: `$foo = $doc->saveHTML(); if (empty($foo)) { die("Ruhroh"); }`

Comment: sorry i tried this and it didn't work. i only get warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the [PHP documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) on DOMDocument::saveHTML.

When DOMDocument::saveHTML fails, it will return false. If you would like to disable libxml errors and fetch them on your own, consider using [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$root = $doc->createElement('html');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$head = $doc->createElement('head');
$head = $root->appendChild($head);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $head->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

$saved = $doc->saveHTML();

if ($saved === false) {
    echo 'Unable to save DOM document';
} else {
    echo $saved;
}
```

To fetch any errors that may have occurred when using libxml errors were disabled, use [libxml_get_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php):

```
if ($errors = libxml_get_errors()) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error->message . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

If you don't care about any of the error messages, you could just use [libxml_get_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-last-error.php) which will return a LibXMLError object if an error occurred, false otherwise.

Comment: Please see me updated answer for information regarding disabling libxml errors.

Comment: that now hides the error but still we cannot know when the loadHTML or saveHTML fails. Can you please look at the updated answer above?

Comment: In my answer, I stated that you must use libxml_get_errors() to see if there are any errors that were suppressed. I've updated my answer to include an example of how to do this. Let me know if it works!